# How to stop a function called infinitely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, http, request

I have this bunch of code which runs infinitely as it can be seen from the terminal img. How can I stop it? Delete function is assigned to a button so I don't know why it runs even though I didn't click that button.

//server.js

```
app.get("/getMaintenanceTypes",(req,res)=>{
      pool.query(`Select * from maintenancetypes`, (err, result) => {
        if(!err){
          console.log("maintanencetypes", result.rows);
          res.status(200).send(result.rows);
        }else{
          res.status(404).json(err.message)
          console.log("maintanencetypes", err.message)
        }
      })
    })
```

//main.js

```
const getMainTypes = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${serverBaseUrl}/getMaintenanceTypes`);
    //console.log("response", response.data);
    const response2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      let entry = {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        description: "",
      };
      entry.id = response.data[i].id;
      entry.title = response.data[i].title;
      entry.description = response.data[i].description;

      response2.push(entry);
      //console.log("entry", entry);
    }
    console.log("RESPONSE2", response2);

    return response2;
  }


async function deleteAllMainTypes() {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.delete(
        `${serverBaseUrl}/deleteAllMainTypes`
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    const maintenanceList = await getMainTypes();
    //console.log("main list", maintenanceList);
    setMaintenanceList(maintenanceList);
  };



const deleteHandler = () => {
    deleteAllMainTypes();
  }





<Button onClick={deleteHandler} >Delete All</Button>
```

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Show how you assign the function

Comment: @KonradLinkowski In button part?

Comment: How many rows does `Select * from maintenancetypes` return, when run in `psql`,  and what is the content of the rows? **Add information as text not images as update to question**.